# Optimally combine single hi-gain 2.4 Ghz antenna with 2.4/5 Ghz router with 3 antennas

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have the following hardware:

- 2.4 [Hawking H-AI6SI](https://www.cnet.com/products/hawking-h-ai6si-antenna/specs/) 2.4 Ghz antenna ([PDF with detailed specs](http://hawkingtech.com/products/downloadfile/433.html))
- [TPLINK TL-WDR4300 dual band router](http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/TL-WDR4300.html) with 3 antennas

**First, can this hi-gain antenna help increase the range/speed of the router?** The antenna is quite older (2003) and perhaps the newer stock antennas are better.

**If so, what is the best way to combine the two pieces of hardware?** Some considerations:

- The router is dual-band and has three antennas, but only two ethernet interfaces. From my understanding, the router dynamically adjusts which antenna each interface uses.
- The hi-gain antenna is rated for 2.4 Ghz and is not dual-band. Perhaps it was before dual-band labeling; could it work for 5 Ghz anyways? Are dual-band antennas constructed differently?
- If my hi-gain antenna doesn't support 5 Ghz, could configuring my router to only use 2.4 Ghz and connecting it to the hi-gain antenna get better results?

**And how can I tell if there was an improvement?**

- The router has OpenWRT installed. On the status page it shows the strength of the wireless signals. However when I tried disabling both ethernet interfaces from the management UI, they didn't really seem to be disabled. I think data was still being transmitted, too.

Answer (score 1):

> First, can this hi-gain antenna help increase the range/speed of the
>   router?

You can increase range but it would be usable in open sight environment due to its directional pattern, take a look at picture that represent diagram of coverage

[image: omni-coverage-pattern]

As about speed, keep in mind - than longer distance then lower speed due to signal strength decreases with the square of the distance and delay in communication between two points.

> The antenna is quite older (2003) and perhaps the newer stock antennas
>   are better.

There nothing changed significantly in antenna's world if we talking about simple omni antennas.

> The router is dual-band and has three antennas, but only two ethernet
>   interfaces. From my understanding, the router dynamically adjusts
>   which antenna each interface uses.

Antennas have nothing common with Ethernet, it isn't related at all. Radio unit using signal from multiple antennas and dynamically choosing that one that has more stronger signal, they aren't all in use all the time. WiFi working on pretty high frequencies that are subject to multiple reflections that is why using multiple antennas can improve signal strength since radio unit can choose better signal from different sources.

> The hi-gain antenna is rated for 2.4 Ghz and is not dual-band. Perhaps
>   it was before dual-band labeling; could it work for 5 Ghz anyways?

No, it wouldn't work well at all. Size or to be more correct - length of antenna  calculated based on wave length it supposed to work on.

> Are dual-band antennas constructed differently?

Yes, manufactures either used two antennas inside of a single stick or what is more common length of antenna calculated as a compromises between two different radio band (which actually reduce quality for both bands)

> If my hi-gain antenna doesn't support 5 Ghz, could configuring my
>   router to only use 2.4 Ghz and connecting it to the hi-gain antenna
>   get better results?

If you using antenna that was designed for 2.4GHz only then you defiantly have to turn off 5GHz, if you don't want [SWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio) get worse that theoretically may kill radio transmitter.
5GHz is good when you have open sight on a short distance that can give you higher speed, but since wave length on 5GHz is shorter (it just 6cm or 2.36 inches) then any obstacle that is large than wave length will absorb radio energy and prevent penetration.

As about "better results" - it is really depended on environment you going to use it. If you need to cover more area outside - it would be better to use hi gain antenna, but if it will be used inside multi floors home then probably you would get negative result.

> And how can I tell if there was an improvement?

The simple way is to use data stream between two points and measure its speed.
Obviously it is  better to use devices that can measure  Amplitude-Frequency-Response of radio signal, but a good one are pretty expensive.
If you are owner of Android phone, use [WiFi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vrem.wifianalyzer) to get a picture of radio signals and compare it with different antennas at destination you want to cover with more stronger WiFi signal.